# In requirements.txt, what does tilde equals (~=) mean?

Tags: python, requirements.txt

In the `requirements.txt` for a Python library I am using, one of the requirements is specified like:

```
mock-django~=0.6.10
```

What does `~=` mean?

Answer (score 405, accepted):

It means it will select the latest version of the package, greater than or equal to 0.6.10, but still in the 0.6.* version, so it won't download 0.7.0 for example. It ensures you will get security fixes but keep backward-compatibility, if the package maintainer respects the semantic versioning (which states that breaking changes should occur only in major versions).

Or, as said by PEP 440:

> For a given release identifier V.N , the compatible release clause is approximately equivalent to the pair of comparison clauses:
>
> `>= V.N, == V.*`

- [Definition in PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release)
- [Complete example here in the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers)

Comment: "approximately"? Are there any exceptions for this equivalence?

Comment: @AXO AFAIK, there's subtleties with pre/post release version matching. Most of the time this won't affect basic usage mostly limited to major/minor version matching anyway.

Answer (score 65):

Adding to the existing answers, I think it's very important to also mention that while

> ~=0.6.10 means >=0.6.10, ==0.6.*

Following is also true

> ~=0.6 means >=0.6, ==0.*

It's mentioned in the [PEP documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release).

Answer (score 44):

That's the 'compatible release' [version specifier](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers).

It's equivalent to: `mock-django >= 0.6.10, == 0.6.*`, and is a tidy way of matching a version which is expected to be compatible. In plain English, it's a bit like saying: "I need a version of mock-django which is at least as new as 0.6.10, but not so new that it isn't compatible with it."

If you're not sure about all this version number stuff, a quick look at the PEP440 [version scheme](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-scheme) should sort you out!

Answer (score 13):

~= means a compatible version. Not less than 0.6.10 and higher (0.6.*).

Answer (score 12):

The full definition of `~=` [Compatible release](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release) (including pre and post release) is:

> A compatible release clause consists of the compatible release
> operator `~=` and a version identifier. It matches any candidate version
> that is expected to be compatible with the specified version.
>
> The specified version identifier must be in the standard format
> described in [Version scheme](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-scheme). Local version identifiers are NOT
> permitted in this version specifier.
>
> For a given release identifier `V.N`, the compatible release clause is
> approximately equivalent to the pair of comparison clauses:

```
>= V.N, == V.*
```

> This operator MUST NOT be used with a single segment version number such as `~=1`.
>
> For example, the following groups of version clauses are equivalent:

```
~= 2.2
>= 2.2, == 2.*

~= 1.4.5
>= 1.4.5, == 1.4.*
```

> If a pre-release, post-release or developmental release is named in a
> compatible release clause as `V.N.suffix`, then the suffix is ignored
> when determining the required prefix match:

```
~= 2.2.post3
>= 2.2.post3, == 2.*

~= 1.4.5a4
>= 1.4.5a4, == 1.4.*
```

> The padding rules for release segment comparisons means that the
> assumed degree of forward compatibility in a compatible release clause
> can be controlled by appending additional zeros to the version
> specifier:

```
~= 2.2.0
>= 2.2.0, == 2.2.*

~= 1.4.5.0
>= 1.4.5.0, == 1.4.5.*
```

**Note that this does NOT work well with semantic versioning pre-releases.**

For instance, `2.3.4.dev123+abc` **should** be `> 2.3.3` and `< 2.3.4`

but `~=2.3.4.dev123+abc` will **NOT** take `2.3.4` when it's released.

Answer (score 4):

> A compatible release clause consists of the compatible release operator ~= and a version identifier. It matches any candidate version that is expected to be compatible with the specified version.

You can read more here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release