# Does pip take into account the actual Python version when installing compatible package versions?

Tags: python, pip

I have a library that has to support several Python versions starting from 2.6. E.g., one of my requirements is `requests`. I know that the last version supporting Python 2.6 is `2.19.1` (the latest version `2.20.0` supports any Python >= 2.7).

So my question is whether `pip` understands that the line `requests~=2.19` in requirements should install `2.19.1` for Python 2.6 and `2.20.0` for any higher version of Python?

Update. The question is not about the syntax, I'm curious whether `pip` is smart enough and in a Python 2.6 environment will be able not to go beyond `0.19.1`.

Comment: might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39590286/10262890

Comment: `requests<=2.19.1 ; python_version<'2.7'`

Comment: Probably not a direct answer to your (updated) question, but some food for thought maybe... The issue with relying on the fact that _pip_ is "_smart enough_", is that _pip_ relies on the project's metadata, and this could be faulty. There could be a new version _2.19.3_ (or _2.21.999_, or whatever in _2.*_) that wrongly advertises itself as compatible with _Python 2.6_ (assume a mistake, not necessarily bad intention), and _pip_ would install it. So it's probably better to be as explicit as possible. But from looking at the specifications, it seems like `requests~=2.19` would do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe yes, *pip* does take into account the version of the currently running *Python* interpreter, to choose an appropriate version (or distribution of a version) of a project to install. So since `pip install 'requests~=2.19'` is the equivalent of `pip install 'requests>=2.19,requests==2.*'`, it should give as of today (*2020-02-18*):

- *requests 2.19.1* on *Python 2.6*; and
- *requests 2.22.0* on *Python 2.7*.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, yes that is possible using [version specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers) in your requirements file.

Example:

```
requests>=2.19.1,<=2.20.0
```

Using the ~= operator would result in a package in the 2.19 package range for Python 2.7, because it means: install a package greater than or equal to version 2.19.1, but still in the 2.19 version.

Comment: Syntax seems wrong to me (probably a comma missing somewhere) and this doesn't answer the question about the `~=` operator.

Comment: i'm sorry, I forgot the comma. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hm, according to the [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file), `requests~=2.19` means `requests>=2.19,requests==2.*`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you're right. There is one thing you need to keep in mind which is it will also take newer versions like 2.3, 2.4 etc, which might cause incompatibility issues later on.