# Python: requirements.txt specify module with two version ranges

Tags: python, pip

I'd like to specify the versions of tensorflow in a Python module. The agreeable versions are:

```
(version >= 1.14.0 and version < 2.0) or (version >= 2.2)
```

Does anyone know how to express this strange situation in a requirements.txt file? I believe there's a syntax for forbidding specific versions of a module, but I haven't been able to find it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [PEP 440 Version Specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers):

```
tensorflow >=1.14.0,!=2.0.*,!= 2.1.*
```

The comma `,` represents a logical **and**.

Note that `requirements.txt` files are used for **pinning** a deployment, I would generally only expect to ever see `==` specifiers used in those files.

Comment: Also interesting: [What does tilde equals ~= mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39590187/1016343) It is a good way to allow minor updates, but not breaking major updates. In some situations, it can be better than `==`.