# python requirements.txt - unexpected dependencies

Tags: python, pip

After running `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

```
# requirements.txt
...

django~=3.1
djangorestframework~=3.12
django-extensions~=3.0
pygraphviz~=1.6
sphinx~=3.3
...
```

I see the wrong version of django:

```
pip freeze

django==3.2.5
```

I suppose one of the packages in `requirements.txt` has it as dependency

- How would I find the culprit?
- How do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Reset the factory run time , create virtual environment and then install the requirements . Check versions then !

Comment: I do every time - it is part of a docker build

Comment: Which editor you are using ?

Comment: Try using `django~=3.1.0` in the requirements. For more information see the @roganjosh 's answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In requirements.txt, what does tilde equals (~=) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590187/in-requirements-txt-what-does-tilde-equals-mean)

Comment: Thanks - stumbled upon the wrong pycharm's exception..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue. This is exactly how [it should work](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies). `django~=3.1` and `3.2.5` don't differ by a major version.

| Operator | Description | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ~= | Any compatible release. Compatible releases are releases that are within the same major or minor version, assuming the package author is using semantic versioning. | `~=3.1`: version 3.1 or later, but not version 4.0 or later. `~=3.1.2`: version 3.1.2 or later, but not version 3.2.0 or later. |