# Which version of TensorFlow is compatible with numpy==1.19.1?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

[lazypredict](https://lazypredict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) requires numpy==1.19.1 version. However, this version of numpy is not compatible with tensorflow. I have tried installing tensorflow 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.4.0 and 2.5.0 and none of these were compatible with numpy==1.19.1.

Which version of tensorflow can I use to have no dependency issues with the packages required for lazypredict ?

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, pypi can't really list the dependencies of packages because of the potentially non deterministic behavior of the setup.py file (https://dustingram.com/articles/2018/03/05/why-pypi-doesnt-know-dependencies/).

However, when I tried to install both packages with anaconda: `conda install lazypredict`
After a while it installed lazypredict-0.2.9 and tensorflow-2.4.3

Though honestly, I would be very surprised if simply installing the most recent version of both packages an ignoring the mismatched dependency would result in any problems (since numpy is usually backwards compatible).

Edit: Now I tried to install mentioned version from above, but pip still complains: `tensorflow 2.4.3 requires numpy~=1.19.2, but you have numpy 1.19.1 which is incompatible.` Therefore, I added the complete list of packages that anaconda wants to install. I am not sure what exactly `~=` means, but apparently anaconda thinks that 1.19.1 satisfies that requirement.

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
_py-xgboost-mutex-2.0      |            cpu_0           8 KB  conda-forge
abseil-cpp-20210324.2      |       he49afe7_0         937 KB  conda-forge
absl-py-1.0.0              |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          95 KB  conda-forge
aiohttp-3.8.1              |   py37h271585c_0         562 KB  conda-forge
aiosignal-1.2.0            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          12 KB  conda-forge
astor-0.8.1                |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          25 KB  conda-forge
astunparse-1.6.3           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          15 KB  conda-forge
async-timeout-4.0.2        |     pyhd8ed1ab_0           9 KB  conda-forge
asynctest-0.13.0           |             py_0          24 KB  conda-forge
attrs-21.4.0               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          49 KB  conda-forge
backports-1.0              |             py_2           4 KB  conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.4|     pyhd8ed1ab_0           9 KB  conda-forge
blinker-1.4                |             py_1          13 KB  conda-forge
brotlipy-0.7.0             |py37h271585c_1003         357 KB  conda-forge
c-ares-1.18.1              |       h0d85af4_0         100 KB  conda-forge
ca-certificates-2021.10.8  |       h033912b_0         139 KB  conda-forge
cachetools-4.2.4           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          12 KB  conda-forge
certifi-2021.10.8          |   py37hf985489_1         145 KB  conda-forge
cffi-1.14.6                |   py37hda351d9_0         218 KB  conda-forge
charset-normalizer-2.0.11  |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          35 KB  conda-forge
click-7.1.2                |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          64 KB  conda-forge
cryptography-36.0.1        |   py37h5e77fcc_0         1.3 MB  conda-forge
dataclasses-0.8            |     pyhc8e2a94_3          10 KB  conda-forge
frozenlist-1.3.0           |   py37h271585c_0          39 KB  conda-forge
gast-0.3.3                 |             py_0          12 KB  conda-forge
giflib-5.2.1               |       hbcb3906_2          71 KB  conda-forge
google-auth-1.35.0         |     pyh6c4a22f_0          81 KB  conda-forge
google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.6 |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          19 KB  conda-forge
google-pasta-0.2.0         |     pyh8c360ce_0          42 KB  conda-forge
grpc-cpp-1.37.1            |       h69eed7d_3         2.8 MB  conda-forge
grpcio-1.37.1              |   py37h87f55f7_0         1.8 MB  conda-forge
h5py-2.10.0                |nompi_py37hdf859c4_106         905 KB  conda-forge
hdf5-1.10.6                |nompi_hc5d9132_1114         3.1 MB  conda-forge
icu-68.2                   |       he49afe7_0        12.7 MB  conda-forge
idna-3.3                   |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          55 KB  conda-forge
importlib-metadata-4.10.1  |   py37hf985489_0          32 KB  conda-forge
importlib_metadata-4.10.1  |       hd8ed1ab_0           4 KB  conda-forge
joblib-1.0.0               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         206 KB  conda-forge
jpeg-9e                    |       h0d85af4_0         252 KB  conda-forge
keras-preprocessing-1.1.2  |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          34 KB  conda-forge
krb5-1.19.2                |       hcfbf3a7_3         1.2 MB  conda-forge
lazypredict-0.2.9          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          15 KB  conda-forge
libblas-3.9.0              |13_osx64_openblas          12 KB  conda-forge
libcblas-3.9.0             |13_osx64_openblas          12 KB  conda-forge
libcurl-7.79.1             |       hf45b732_1         317 KB  conda-forge
libedit-3.1.20191231       |       h0678c8f_2         103 KB  conda-forge
libev-4.33                 |       haf1e3a3_1          99 KB  conda-forge
libgfortran-5.0.0          |9_3_0_h6c81a4c_23          19 KB  conda-forge
libgfortran5-9.3.0         |      h6c81a4c_23         1.7 MB  conda-forge
liblapack-3.9.0            |13_osx64_openblas          12 KB  conda-forge
libnghttp2-1.43.0          |       h6f36284_1         867 KB  conda-forge
libopenblas-0.3.18         |openmp_h3351f45_0         9.0 MB  conda-forge
libpng-1.6.37              |       h7cec526_2         313 KB  conda-forge
libprotobuf-3.15.8         |       hcf210ce_1         2.2 MB  conda-forge
libssh2-1.10.0             |       h52ee1ee_2         221 KB  conda-forge
libxgboost-1.5.1           |       h4a89273_0         2.2 MB  conda-forge
lightgbm-2.3.1             |   py37h4a8c4bd_0         715 KB  conda-forge
llvm-openmp-12.0.1         |       hda6cdc1_1         287 KB  conda-forge
markdown-3.3.6             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          67 KB  conda-forge
more-itertools-8.12.0      |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          47 KB  conda-forge
multidict-6.0.2            |   py37h271585c_0          45 KB  conda-forge
numpy-1.19.1               |   py37h1efc2f6_2         5.1 MB  conda-forge
oauthlib-3.2.0             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          90 KB  conda-forge
openssl-1.1.1l             |       h0d85af4_0         1.9 MB  conda-forge
opt_einsum-3.3.0           |     pyhd8ed1ab_1          53 KB  conda-forge
packaging-21.3             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          36 KB  conda-forge
pandas-1.0.5               |   py37h94625e5_0         9.6 MB  conda-forge
pluggy-0.13.1              |   py37hf985489_4          29 KB  conda-forge
protobuf-3.15.8            |   py37hd8d24ac_0         323 KB  conda-forge
py-1.11.0                  |     pyh6c4a22f_0          74 KB  conda-forge
py-xgboost-1.5.1           |   py37hf985489_0         150 KB  conda-forge
pyasn1-0.4.8               |             py_0          53 KB  conda-forge
pyasn1-modules-0.2.7       |             py_0          60 KB  conda-forge
pycparser-2.21             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         100 KB  conda-forge
pyjwt-2.3.0                |     pyhd8ed1ab_1          18 KB  conda-forge
pyopenssl-22.0.0           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          49 KB  conda-forge
pyparsing-3.0.7            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          79 KB  conda-forge
pysocks-1.7.1              |   py37hf985489_4          28 KB  conda-forge
pytest-5.4.3               |   py37hc8dfbb8_0         384 KB  conda-forge
python-dateutil-2.8.2      |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         240 KB  conda-forge
python-flatbuffers-1.12    |     pyhd8ed1ab_1          19 KB  conda-forge
python_abi-3.7             |          2_cp37m           4 KB  conda-forge
pytz-2021.3                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         242 KB  conda-forge
pyu2f-0.1.5                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          31 KB  conda-forge
pyyaml-5.3.1               |   py37hf967b71_2         171 KB  conda-forge
re2-2021.08.01             |       he49afe7_0         193 KB  conda-forge
requests-2.27.1            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          53 KB  conda-forge
requests-oauthlib-1.3.1    |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          22 KB  conda-forge
rsa-4.8                    |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          31 KB  conda-forge
scikit-learn-0.23.1        |   py37hf5857e7_0         6.3 MB  conda-forge
scipy-1.7.3                |   py37h4e3cf02_0        19.7 MB  conda-forge
six-1.15.0                 |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          14 KB  conda-forge
snappy-1.1.8               |       hb1e8313_3          29 KB  conda-forge
tensorboard-2.4.1          |     pyhd8ed1ab_1         8.8 MB  conda-forge
tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.8.1|     pyhd8ed1ab_0         668 KB  conda-forge
tensorflow-2.4.3           |   py37hf985489_0          25 KB  conda-forge
tensorflow-base-2.4.3      |   py37h05ab19a_0       116.3 MB  conda-forge
tensorflow-estimator-2.4.0 |     pyh9656e83_0         289 KB  conda-forge
termcolor-1.1.0            |             py_2           6 KB  conda-forge
threadpoolctl-3.1.0        |     pyh8a188c0_0          18 KB  conda-forge
tqdm-4.56.0                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          76 KB  conda-forge
typing-extensions-3.7.4.3  |                0           8 KB  conda-forge
typing_extensions-3.7.4.3  |             py_0          25 KB  conda-forge
urllib3-1.26.8             |     pyhd8ed1ab_1         100 KB  conda-forge
wcwidth-0.2.5              |     pyh9f0ad1d_2          33 KB  conda-forge
werkzeug-2.0.2             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         221 KB  conda-forge
wrapt-1.13.3               |   py37h271585c_1          44 KB  conda-forge
xgboost-1.5.1              |   py37h3f6e5c9_0          12 KB  conda-forge
yaml-0.2.5                 |       h0d85af4_2          82 KB  conda-forge
yarl-1.7.2                 |   py37h271585c_1         127 KB  conda-forge
zipp-3.7.0                 |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          12 KB  conda-forge
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:       217.4 MB
```

Comment: `~=1.19.2` means, pick a version which is at least 1.19.2. It will favour a greater version but in the 1.19.* series, not 1.20.*. This is explained more elaborately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590187/in-requirements-txt-what-does-tilde-equals-mean#:~:text=5%20Answers&text=It%20means%20it%20will%20select,than%20or%20equal%20to%200.6.)