# What is a format of PyPi's requires_dist in JSON API

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

PyPi provides a [JSON API](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIJSON) to query information about packages. It includes a field with the package's  dependencies called `info`/`requires_dist`.

Sample data (from [`requests`](https://pypi.org/pypi/requests/json) package):

```
urllib3 (<1.27,>=1.21.1)
certifi (>=2017.4.17)
chardet (<5,>=3.0.2) ; python_version < "3"
idna (<3,>=2.5) ; python_version < "3"
charset-normalizer (~=2.0.0) ; python_version >= "3"
idna (<4,>=2.5) ; python_version >= "3"
PySocks (!=1.5.7,>=1.5.6) ; extra == 'socks'
win-inet-pton ; (sys_platform == "win32" and python_version == "2.7") and extra == 'socks'
chardet (<5,>=3.0.2) ; extra == 'use_chardet_on_py3'
```

What is the format of that data? Is there any documentation on it?

And more specifically: What does exactly `~=` mean? And what is set of supported "variables" (like `sys_platform` and `python_version`)?

Comment: Check [In requirements.txt, what does tilde equals (~=) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39590187/4046632)

Comment: @buran, thanks, at least it explains the `~=`…

Comment: Here is the spec: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/

Comment: Note that key is `requires_dist`, not `requres_deps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec is in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/.

An explanation of `~=` is in [In requirements.txt, what does tilde equals (~=) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39590187/4046632).